# Issues with rendering a custom header component in the header bar of React-Native navigation

Tags: header, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using the following code for React-Navigation where I use Stack Navigation to render the screens. I have a custom component named Header which I am rendering in the header bar. I am setting the background color in my Header component itself. But how can I make the orange background cover the entire width? Here is the screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

The following is my code for navigation:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Detail from "../screens/Detail";
import Header from "../components/Header";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerTitle: () => <Header navigation={navigation} />,
         
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Detail"
        component={Detail}
        options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.title })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default HomeStack;
```

The following is the code in my custom Header component:

```
const Header = ({ navigation, title }) => {
  const openMenu = () => {
    navigation.openDrawer();
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <AntDesign
        name="menufold"
        style={styles.icon}
        size={28}
        color="black"
        onPress={openMenu}
      />
      <View style={styles.headerTitle}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "tomato",
  },
  headerText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#fff",
    letterSpacing: 1,
  },
  icon: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 16,
  },
  headerTitle: {
    height: 60,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the Header Styles in the options prop of the Stack.
In the options where you specify the `headerTitle: () => <Header />` Custom Component,
add this `headerStyle : { backgroundColor: 'tomato' }`

Comment: If I set the headerStyle in options prop of the stack, the entire status bar's background color becomes tomato. I wanted to have a header that looks like the google hangouts app header. You can see there is a custom header that spans the width of the entire screen and there are different shades of green: https://www.phonedog.com/sites/phonedog.com/files/styles/blog_entry/public/blog/content_images/2017/03/googlehangoutschat.jpg?itok=wdobOGJf

Comment: I think you are confusing the StausBar Color style with the Header Component styling. StatusBar is the top bar where, you see time, network status etc.,... to set Status bar color use <StatusBar backgroundColor="darkGreen" /> Component of React Native. P.S. Replace "darkGreen" with your choice of color

Answer (score 0):

for height it works like this

```
minHeight: '100%'
```

but for width it not works

```
minWidth: '100%'
```

Answer (score 0):

A year later, I encountered same issue...
In my case, I needed to set a custom header for all screens, sooo `screenOptions` right?

well, this worked

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions = {{
            header: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
        }}
    >
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home_post} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```